# Hook in befor App.Exit

Tags: c#, wpf, controls, resource-cleanup, application-shutdown

Here is my problem:

In my WPF application I have a `MyBaseControl` (derives from `System.Windows.Controls.ContentControls`) and a lot of `MyCustomControls` which derives from `MyBaseControl`. I need to do some storing and cleanup operations for all my `MyCustomControls` befor the application is closed.
Here is some code:

```
public abstract class MyBaseControl : ContentControl
{
// Do some smart stuff.
}

App.Exit += new System.Windows.ExitEventHandler(App.App_OnExit);
```

In `App_OnExit()` I do the really last operations that need to be done.
I tried to do my cleanup operations in the destructor of `MyBaseControl` but this is called after `App_OnExit()`. Same problem with `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit`.

The `ContentControl.Closed` and `ContentControl.Unloaded` events don't occour when I exit the application via ALT+F4.

Where can I hook in to do my cleanup operations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Where can I hook in to do my cleanup operations?

In a `Closing` event handler for the parent window of the control:

```
public abstract class MyBaseControl : ContentControl
{
    public MyBaseControl()
    {
        Loaded += MyBaseControl_Loaded;
    }

    private void MyBaseControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Window parentWindow = Window.GetWindow(this);
        parentWindow.Closing += ParentWindow_Closing;
        Loaded -= MyBaseControl_Loaded;
    }

    private void ParentWindow_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        //cleanup...
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can put it to your application class:

```
public delegate void TimeToCleanUpEventHandler();
public event TimeToCleanUpEventHandler TimeToCleanUp;
```

modify Exit event handler:

```
App.Current.Exit += ((o, e) => { TimeToCleanUp?.Invoke(); App.App_OnExit(o, e); });
```

and modify your base control:

```
public abstract class MyBaseControl : ContentControl
{
    public MyBaseControl()
    {
        (App.Current as MyApp).TimeToCleanUp += CleanItUp;
    }

    public virtual void CleanItUp()
    {
        (App.Current as MyApp).TimeToCleanUp -= CleanItUp;
        //do stuff;
    }
}
```